# Optimize mongodb with right index

Tags: mongodb

I am super new to mongodb. So perhaps i am doing this query completely wrong. I have a query that is suppose to check friend status with other users. But the problematic part is that my query is way too slow. It takes about 20s to finish the search.

So either i have no clue how to create correct indexes. Or i have no clue to write this query to keep the performance

**The query**

```
  return await ProfileModel.aggregate([
    {
      '$lookup': {
        'from': 'friends', 
        'let': {
          'friends': '$friends'
        }, 
        'pipeline': [
          {
            '$match': {
              'recipient': new ObjectId(myUserObjId), 
              '$expr': {
                '$in': [
                  '$_id', '$$friends'
                ]
              }
            }
          }, {
            '$project': {
              'status': 1
            }
          }
        ], 
        'as': 'friendsResult'
      }
    }, {
      '$addFields': {
        'friendsStatus': {
          '$ifNull': [
            {
              '$min': '$friendsResult.status'
            }, 0
          ]
        }
      }
    }, {
      '$match': {
        'friendsStatus': {
          '$gt': 0
        }
      }
    }, {
      '$project': {
        'username': 1, 
        'uid': 1, 
        'profilePicture': 1, 
        'friendsStatus': 1,
        'locale': 1
      }
    }
  ])
```

This query goes thru all profiles and check if that profile is friends with that user. But the problem is that the more users i have. The longer this query is going to take. So i appreciate any feedback on how i should do this

Comment: `pipeline` is powerful but less efficient than other stages. Try rewriting your aggregation pipeline without it. $expr/$in may not be using indexes. Execute `explain` to verify

Comment: That aggregation will examine every profile in the collection and for each profile, examine all of the friends and check each to see if `myUserObjId` is there.  That is a lot of comparison and doesn't scale well.  If you could edit the question to describe the model we might be able to help you find a different way to get the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only index I can think of is the `recipient` key in `friends` collection.

```
db.friends.createIndex({"recipient": 1})
```

I think your Aggregation query can be optimized further ny altering the Pipeline Stages. Give the below query a try to see if it improves performance.

```
db.test2.aggregate([
    {
      '$lookup': {
        'from': 'friends', 
        'let': {
          'friends': '$friends'
        }, 
        'pipeline': [
          {
            '$match': {
              'recipient': new ObjectId(), 
              'status': {'$gt': 0},  // Modified
              '$expr': {
                '$in': [
                  '$_id', '$$friends'
                ]
              }
            }
          }, {
            '$group': {  // Modified in place of `$project` stage
              '_id': null,
              'statuses': {'$push': '$status'}
            }
          }
        ], 
        'as': 'friendsResult'
      }
    }, {
      '$match': {  // Modified
        'friendsStatus.statuses': {
          '$ne': []
        }
      }
    },
    {  // Modified from your Stage orer
      '$project': {
        'username': 1, 
        'uid': 1, 
        'profilePicture': 1, 
        'friendsStatus': {"$min": "$friendsResult.statuses"},
        'locale': 1
      }
    }
])
```

I haven't tested the above Aggregation query, so let me know if it's not working with sample input data.

If you are using the aggregation query which I provided, use the below compound index instead.

```
db.friends.createIndex({"recipient": 1, "status": 1})
```

> **Note:** The `pipeline` is powerful and efficient if you use it correctly, so don't hesitate to use it. Also, `$expr/$in` does use single key MongoDB-indexing as some people are doubtful about it.